# Prove $G = \left\{ \mathrm{diag} (e^{ti}, e^{\lambda ti}) \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$ is not a manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups

Let $\lambda$ be an irrational number. Let $G \subset G_2(\mathbb{C})$ be defined as $G = \left\{ \mathrm{diag} (e^{ti}, e^{\lambda ti}) \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$. Prove that $G$ is not a manifold.

The definition I am using for a manifold of dimension $n$ is a set $X \subset \mathbb R^m$ such that, for all $x \in X$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$ that is homeomorphic to an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$, where the homeomorphism $f\colon U \to V$ is smooth and has a smooth inverse (the latter meaning that $f^{-1}$ extends to a smooth map on an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$ containing $V$).

Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $G$ contains points of the form $\mathrm{diag} (1, e^{\lambda 2\pi ni})$ arbitrarily close to the identity and for arbitrarily large $n$. Also, the map $\mathbb{R} \to G$ defining this group is injective.

Comment: Observe that $G$ is homeomorphic to the winding line $(e^{it},e^{\lambda it})$ in the torus $\{(e^{it},e^{is}):s,t\in[0,2\pi)\}$ and prove that the winding line is not a manifold. Need to use the fact that $\mathbb Z[\lambda]$ - the ring extension of $\mathbb Z$ by adjoining $\lambda$ - is dense in $\mathbb R$

Comment: I think that's a good way to go about it. I am having difficulty in figuring out what technique needs to be used to prove it's not a manifold. Should I be looking at tangent spaces? Should I try by contradiction? I've been trying both of these and more and just can't pin anything down. Is there any more of a hint you can offer?

Comment: Aneesh's comment sort of gives the best hint. But if you need elaboration then the set that you speak of is a subgroup of $ GL(2,\mathbb C) $ but it is not closed.I hope you already proved this. Your comment seems to indicate as such. It is in fact dense in the torus employing the homeomorphism Aneesh pointed out.(This means it is not a Matrix Lie Group and hence not a Lie Group).Maybe that helps. It is a group but not a Lie group

Comment: Have a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus. I would be interested in knowing your progress.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not a Lie Group; was having trouble using that to any advantage. Appreciate the comment!

Comment: I was of the view that any group is a Lie Group if and only if it is a differentiable manifold. Am I right? I am learning myself.So my ideas will be hazy at best.

Comment: @Vishesh, also part of the definition is that the group operation and inversion are smooth maps.

Comment: I do not know the answer to that question off the top of my head (new to the subject). Here is a conceptually clear proof that I think we can "agree" on: Pick a point on the winding line and consider any neighborhood of that point in the torus. We "know" that this neighborhood contains a bunch of "stripes" representing where the winding line is and isn't on the torus. Such a neighborhood cannot be connected upon intersecting with $G$. Therefore, no homeomorphism can exist between the resulting neighborhood in $G$ and some $n$-ball.

Comment: Correct absolutely! Turn this into an answer if you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* You  can show that every suffciently small neighbourhood of $1\in G$ is disconnected